# leanModal not a function

Tags: jquery

Hopefully you can help me clear this up. I'm using a few jQuery scripts on my site (one being `leanModal`, which I've used several times in the past without any problems). The site I'm working on (using WP) was working fine, until a few hours ago the modal stopped working. Looking at the error console it states:

```
$ is not a function
$("a#go").leanModal();

$ is not a function
$(function() {
```

Both relate to `leanModal`. Any ideas why suddenly such an error would occur?

Site for reference is here (http://richgc.com/freelance/industry/) and the modal is fired by clicking 'Information'.

Comment: You either modified the `leanModal` script include in the HTML header or you moved the `leanModal` script file away from the location you referenced in the header. Either that or you did one of the above for your jQuery source.

Comment: `$ is not a function` indicates that jQuery is not loaded (or overwritten by something else). You have to make sure that you are including jQuery properly.

Comment: @FelixKling. Or `noConflict()` was used... Rocket found it in his code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you override the `$` in some way.

`$` is `undefined`
`jQuery` return a jQuery object. (`function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}`)

---

As **@Rocket** found in your's source code:

You use `jQuery.noConflict();` [here](http://richgc.com/freelance/industry/index.php?wpsc_user_dynamic_js=true&ver=3.%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B8.8.525805)

Which free the `$` varibale to it's previous state (`undefined`)

Read `noConflict` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> Description: Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable

Comment: Actually overriding the `$` would cause it to equal something else, and it wouldn't be undefined unless of course the OP said `$ = undefined`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. It can be done with [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), and other ways as well...

Comment: What are you referring to, exactly? What can be done with `noConflict`?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: `noConflict` restores `$` to what it was before jQuery was loaded.  Which is probably `undefined`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. `Description: Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable`

Comment: @gdoron: I went digging through his source, and yep he has a `jQuery.noConflict();` in `http://richgc.com/freelance/industry/index.php?wpsc_user_dynamic_js=true&ver=3.8.8.525805`.

Comment: @Rocket. Nice dig... :) added it with your name.

Comment: Ah yes... how odd. This is being included by a WP plugin. Unsure how this is loaded in... I'll have a look around. Why would a plugin want to use jQuery.noConflict();?

Comment: I'm guessing, reading the docs, perhaps another JS library is needed. A bit risky including that in a WP plugin. Anyway, I've removed the call for now and everything seems to work nicely. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks guys :)