# Javascript vs. Jquery: Initializing Modals. Fuction not recognized in JS, but in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using some modals from here http://materializecss.com/modals.html#! and I have an arbitrary question regarding the replacement of jquery with javascript.

I have this function, which executes as soon as the document is ready:

```
ready: function() {
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal(); // line 1 works
    document.querySelector(".modal-trigger").leanModal(); // this line does not work
}
```

Up until now my understanding was that jQuery can be replaced with Javascript, but line two does not work, because I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).leanModal is not a function
```

Am I doing something wrong in my Javascript? Is there a better method to replace

```
$('.modal-triger')
```

?

Comment: `leanModal` is a jQuery plugin, so that's no suprise ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390338/leanmodal-not-a-function ;)

Comment: jQuery is a set of functions others wrote in javascript... it's not a language, it's just normal code others wrote to make life easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a jQuery plugin. It's defined on the prototype chain of jQuery objects. It's not going to work on a raw DOM node.

It's defined somewhere like this:

```
$.fn.leanModal = function () { ... };
```

Which means it only works on jQuery objects: `$(...)`.

To expand:

`$()` is used as a constructor function, it creates new objects. Objects in JavaScript inherit methods from their prototype chain.

`$.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`.

You can extend any object's prototype at any time, and all objects that inherit that prototype will gain the new method. You could extend `Node` objects by attaching a method to their prototype.

```js
Node.prototype.leanModal = (Node.prototype.leanModal || function () {
  window.alert(document.body instanceof Node);
});


document.body.leanModal();
```

Note: some folk are very much against the modification of native prototypes (Number, Node, Function, String, etc...). It's okay to do so in modern browsers*, as long as you do it sanely and don't override something that already exists. *All* objects inherit from `Object.prototype` so you'll want to modify that one extra carefully.

**The worry exists from the fact that extending certain prototypes causes issues in IE6/7/8. Using `Object.defineProperty` is a slightly safer method in IE8.*

Comment: Thank you Oka, didn't knew that leanModal is a jQuery function.